# Monero GUI 0.17.1.9 'not supported' on this type of Mac

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I downloaded the Monero GUI 0.17.1.9 .dmg, but when I opened the disk image, the GUI app icon has a slashed circle across it, it's 'Not Supported on this type of Mac'. I previously ran v0.13.0.4  or the version just prior to it.

I'm running macOS 10.13.6.

How do I get this to run on this machine? Or is there an earlier version I have to use?

Thanks.

Comment: and where does one find system requirements? I looked in a lot of places on monero.org and mymonero.org but was unsuccessful at finding that info...

Comment: What model of Mac are you running it on?

Comment: I's a mid-2011 27 inch iMac, 3.4 GHz Intel  i7

Comment: macOS 10.13.6 Hight Sierra

Comment: I'm on 10.3.6 High Sierra too, (MBP Mid 2012) and 0.17.1.9 works here. (just double checked and connects and syncs to my local docker node)  I Had been running 10.9 and couldn't run the GUI a while back but the CLI worked fine; something to try.

Comment: Hmmm, wonder if it has to do with the vintage of the iMac…

Comment: Could always try compiling from source?